# NHibernate 3.x: Same table, three mappings, each result three times

Tags: c#, .net, sql, nhibernate, queryover

I've three entity types: A, B and C.

These are mapped to the same database table.

B and C inherit A.

There're three records in the database table which is mapped by A, B and C.

Whenever I remain B and C mapped in the configuration file, I get each entity three times.

I've tried to remove mappings for B and C, and then, I get the whole number of entities: three.

Finally, I've profiled SQL Server and the query started from the application is translated into three SQL SELECT commands.

How can I avoid this? Or I want to know if it's possible to map N classes to the same table without meaning that trying to get an entity would end in retrieving it as many times as target table is mapped.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Can you post some code, mappings and some examples of what is being returned vs what you are expecting.

Comment: Double-check my text then. 1 table maped by 3 entities. I've 3 records. When I try to retrieve these records as entities, I get 9 results (each entity, duplicated). Thank you.

Comment: Another detail: I've tried to do same thing with Query Over and HQL criteria. Same result.

Comment: @Mattias It's still worthwhile to show us your data structure and mappings as it's hard to help, when we don't know what we're dealing with.

Comment: @Vadim, See Jamie Ide answer. I believe there's no need of code, I was looking for this kind of answer. I know some other scenarios need code and samples, but this is more about I had a lack of knowledge - if I need to be honest...-.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to map the class hierarchy using an inheritance mapping strategy, not by mapping each concrete class individually. Since you already store all three types in one table you should use table-per-class mapping. See [this](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/10/nhibernate-mapping-ndash-inheritance.aspx) and [this](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-8-inheritance-mapping/1nr4enxv3dpeq/11#).

Comment: I'll look forward for this documentation. It sounds good. I'll mark as correct during tomorrow! Thank you.